# how to use gridview control in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

how to use gridview control in my silverlight xaml page in asp.net & c#.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout official [silverlight.net](http://www.silverlight.net/search/?q=gridview) site

Check this tutorial which demonstrates DataGrid in silverlight... http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/sqldatagrid-cs/